# ReportViewer Error VS 2019 Community method not found?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, reportviewer

How can I get the ReportViewer to work in Visual Studio 2019 Community? I've followed the instructions to get the report designer and viewer in Visual Studio toolbox.  When I drag a ReportViewer onto a blank form I receive this error:

[image]

I went through these posted to see if it will help, but i'm still stuck.  I've even install a fresh copy of visual studio with no luck.
[error opening reportviwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939582/i-can-not-get-the-report-viewer-to-work-on-vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

It was actually an error with the .net framework I was using.  Apparently, the reportViewer is not compatible with .net5.  I had to create a new project, selecting the correct type: 'Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)'

Do not select: 'Windows Forms App'  It will not target the correct framework.